# Animated wrapping line and wrapping cylinder

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, animation, video

I am trying to draw the following situation using any graphic program but I couldn't since I don't know how to make the animation. So your help is greatly appreciated.

So my picture consists of two objects:

In the bottom of the page, a torus with animated "irrational" line wrapping the torus
like this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfKxzKM-MNc)

And above this torus, a pipe (cylindrical line) animated simultaneously with wrapping line in the tours. (For example like this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTWKEmEvhbE) but in our situation the pipe doesn't close up!)

Comment: Is this question about Wolfram Mathematica? If so, are you aware of ParametricPlot3D?

Comment: Yes it is a about Wolfram but I don't know about ParametricPlot3D!

Comment: Then hit F1 and try it?

Comment: Can you make animation too?

Comment: You can look up "GIF" in the documentation to see how to export an animation.